# How can I pass string path param containing slash character?

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I have this REST resource:

```
@GET
@Path("{business},{year},{sample}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getSample(
        @PathParam("business") String business,
        @PathParam("year") String year,
        @PathParam("sample") String sampleId {
    Sample sample = dao.findSample(business, year, sampleId);
    return Response.ok(sample).build();
}
```

`sample` param can contain slash character: `6576/M982`, for instance.

I'm calling it with `http://ip:port/samples/2000,2006,6576/M982` but does not work, obviously.

I have also tried with `http://ip:port/samples/2000,2006,6576%2FM982`, encoding the slash as `%2F`, but doesn't work either, it doesn't reach the endpoint.

**EDIT**

I'm using Retrofit to call the endpoint and I do this:

```
@GET("/samples/{business},{year},{sampleId}")
Observable<Sample> getSampleById(
        @Path("business") String business,
        @Path("year") String year,
        @Path(value = "sampleId", encoded = true) String sampleId);
```

With `encoded = true`, but still not working.

Comment: You have to `URLEncode` it.

Comment: Have you tried `@GET("/samples/{business}%2C{year}%2C{sampleId}")`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Reserved characters such as `,` and `/` must be URL encoded.

- `,` is encoded as `%2C`
- `/` is encoded as `%2F`

Try `http://ip:port/samples/2000%2C2006%2C6576%2FM982`.

---

The [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) defines the following set of [reserved characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) that can be used as delimiters. Hence, they require URL encoding:

```
: / ? # / [ ] / @ ! $ & ' ( ) * + , ; =
```

[Unreserved characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3) do not require URL encoding:

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 - _ . ~
```

---

If URL encoding `,` is not a good alternative for you, you could consider using query parameters. Your code will be like:

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getSample(@QueryParam("business") String business, 
                          @QueryParam("year") String year,
                          @QueryParam("sample") String sampleId {
    ...
}
```

And your URL will be like `http://ip:port/samples?business=2000&year=2006&sample=6576%2FM982`.

Please note that the `/` still needs to be URL encoded.

Comment: "Reserved characters such as , and / must be URL encoded."

Although true of querysting content, that's not necessarily true for path content. From the same rfc: "Thus, characters in the reserved set are protected from normalization and are therefore safe to be used by scheme-specific and producer-specific algorithms for delimiting data subcomponents within a URI."
So it's okay not to encode the slashes if they're being used as path delimiters. Furthermore, encoded slashes will get you in trouble with some webservers (tomcat)

Comment: @Amalgovinus That's true. However, in the OP situation, looks like the `/` is not a path delimiter. So it's okay to encode.

Comment: Note that URLs containing %2F are blocked by many http and application servers, because bugs in old http servers meant that would decode the %2F and treat it as a path delimiter without apply path secuirty checks

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `{sample:.+}` instead of `{sample}`

The `@Path` annotation is a regular expression and regex do not match `/` character.

To override the regex, we can add `.+` at the end of the `PathParam`.

In this way we can allow `/` in our path and avoid using `%2F`.

Comment: Insufficient explanation

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `.+` helped. Just that it needs to be part of `@Path` but not `@PathParam`.

Example:

```
@Path("{sample:.+}")
```