# Java Rest API JAX-RS URL

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jax-rs

I have a java app that looks like the below code. I need to be able to pass it a username, password and url to perform a task. what will the url call look like?

username will be an email so : myemail@mail.com
password is just a string
url will be: like : hhtps://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0

So far I have this url but it's not working

```
localhost:8080/myAPP/webapi/myapi?user=some@email.com&pass=jsjjsd&url=hhtps://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0
```

class code

```
@Path("/myapi")
public class myClass(){


@GET
@Path("/{user}/{pass}/{url}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String foo(@PathParam("user") String user,
                    @PathParam("pass") String pass,
                    @PathParam("url") String url) {
     return "test";
}

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to expose the password in the URL? Luckily I'm not using your API!

Answer (score 1):

Sending sensitive data in the URL is a pretty bad idea. **Never ever do it.** The requested URL is logged by servers and proxies. If the URL is requested by a browser, the URL goes to the browser history. *It's a security breach.*

### What you shouldn't do

Find below two *bad approaches* that you must never use.

If your endpoint is like:

```java
@Path("/myapi")
public class MyResource() {

    @GET
    @Path("/{user}/{pass}/{url}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String foo(@PathParam("user") String user,
                      @PathParam("pass") String pass,
                      @PathParam("url") String url) {
         ...
    }
}
```

The request would be like:

```
GET /myAPP/webapi/myapi/some%40email.com/jsjjsd/https%3A%2F%2Flogin.salesforce.com%2Fservices%2FSoap%2Fu%2F37.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: application/json
```

If your endpoint is like:

```java
@Path("/myapi")
public class MyResource() {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String foo(@QueryParam("user") String user,
                      @QueryParam("pass") String pass,
                      @QueryParam("url") String url) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The request would be like:

```
GET /myAPP/webapi/myapi?user=some%40email.com&pass=jsjjsd&url=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.salesforce.com%2Fservices%2FSoap%2Fu%2F37.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: application/json
```

Please mind the parameter values are URL encoded. For further reference, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38435903/1426227).

### What you should do

When sending sensitive data over the wire, the use of HTTPS is highly advisable. [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) will protect you against the man-in-the-middle attack. For a Certification Authority, you may consider [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). It claims to be free, automated, and open.

Instead of sending those parameters in the URL, you should send them in the request payload using [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3). The request payload could be a JSON, for example. Once you are using JAX-RS, you can use a JSON provider such as Jackson.

To do it, define a bean like the following:

```java
public class Credentials implements Serializable {

    private String user;
    private String pass;
    private String url;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

And consume it in your resource method:

```java
@Path("/myapi")
public class MyResource() {

    @POST
    @Consumer(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String foo(Credentials credentials) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The request would be like:

```
POST /myAPP/webapi/myapi HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{
  "user": "some@email.com",
  "pass": "jsjjsd",
  "url": "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's incorrect your url. In your method you are defining pathParams but your url have queryParams.

Change the your url or method.

The main error is your implementation. It's a terrible security practice send credential via URL in plain text. Consider use any encryption for password and manage token for your application. The URL to login would be manage by the backend. Consider use a POST method.

Look this. [Best practice for REST token-based authentication with JAX-RS and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey)

Regards

Answer (score -2):

You have to use `QueryParam` annotation instead.

**Example :**

```
@Path("/myapi")
public class myClass(){

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String foo(@QueryParam("user") String user,
        @QueryParam("pass") String pass,
        @QueryParam("url") String url) {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sending passwords in the URL is a **pretty bad idea**.

Comment: I agree. But it doesn't the solution is wrong. It just means the approach to the problem is wrong.

Comment: The solution provided is partially correct: the query parameter values must be URL encoded. But always mind the approach is bad and the OP should not be encouraged to follow the wrong path.