# Need to pass backslashes in query string with pretty urls

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, urlencode, pretty-urls

I'm trying to pass a backslash as part of a query string argument.

The project uses a pretty simple `url_rewriting` method:

```
//.Htaccess
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php?arguments=$0 [NC,L]
```

Then receive `$_GET['arguments']` with values separated by **/**

*Ex.:* blog/post/2/ will fill `$_GET['arguments']` with: *'post/2/'*

The problem is, when I try to pass something like *test%5Cabc* (url encoded for *test\abc*), the request returns a 404 error instead of passing it as an argument

I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get a 404 error is because by default, Apache has [AllowEncodedSlashes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) turned off, and its behavior is to 404 any request containing a backslash.  This is because having it turned on is a [potential security hazard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5942780/why-is-it-a-security-risk-to-allow-encoded-slashes-in-a-uri).  In Apache 2.2.18 and later, there is a NoDecode setting which makes this a bit safer, and works well for your case.

Anyway I tried turning it on locally, and indeed this script:

```
<?php var_dump($_REQUEST); ?>
```

is able to handle urls like

```
http://localhost/this\is\a\test
```

and outputs

```
array(1) { ["arguments"]=> string(14) "this\is\a\test" }
```

However, it (or my browser) seems to have problems with encoded backslashes, converting them to regular backslashes - maybe that's not a problem.  If you enable the B flag on your rewriterule, it will convert unencoded backslashes to encoded backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got you right, try using this :

```
'/file.php?id=$value'//this utilise that backslash and then pass the id to the `$_Get[]` Function somewhere in the file.php.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already got it working, the problem is when i try to pass a string like this one: 'test\\abc'. Using urlencode already.