# Why Does url-encoding the first slash after the domain break the url?

Tags: javascript, url, hyperlink, urlencode

Salvete!  I have discovered that a certain way of url encoding breaks the link.  For the record `%2f` represents the forward slash character: `/`

Now, consider this:
Original Link: `http://dottech.org/95285/this-is-the-pacific-barreleye-a-fish-with-a-transparent-head-amazing-photo-of-the-day`

javascript (`encodeURIComponent`) urlencoded link: `http://dottech.org%2f95285%2fthis-is-the-pacific-barreleye-a-fish-with-a-transparent-head-amazing-photo-of-the-day`

Now, if you paste the encoded link into your browser's address bar, it is broken (Firefox, Chrome, IE).

However, if you don't url-encode the **first** forward slash, it works perfectly:
'`http://dottech.org/95285%2fthis-is-the-pacific-barreleye-a-fish-with-a-transparent-head-amazing-photo-of-the-day`

Why?

Comment: To encode a complete URL use encodeURI- encodeURIComponent encodes pieces of an url location- protocol,host,port,pathname,hash and search

Comment: Related post - [Is a slash (“/”) equivalent to an encoded slash (“%2F”) in the path portion of an HTTP URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1957115/465053) & [How to URL Encode a Backslash with R/RCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26304172)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/` is a reserved character. It’s *not* equivalent to `%2f`. If you need the slash *without* its defined meaning, you’d use the encoded form.

See [RFC 3986: "Reserved Characters"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2):

> The purpose of reserved characters is to provide a set of delimiting
> characters that are distinguishable from other data within a URI.
> URIs that differ in the replacement of a reserved character with its
> corresponding percent-encoded octet are not equivalent.  Percent-
> encoding a reserved character, or decoding a percent-encoded octet
> that corresponds to a reserved character, will change how the URI is
> interpreted by most applications.

The reason why the mentionend URL still works if you don’t use the reserved char `/` for the second slash: their CMS simply looks for the ID part in the URL. So you can add whatever you want to the URL, e.g. the following should still work:

```
http://dottech.org/95285/hey-this-URL-got-featured-at-stackoverflow
```

(However, it seems that it still has to be `/` or `%2f` in their case.)

If you try it with a Wikipedia article, it redirects to the front page:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki%2fStack_Overflow
```

Comment: Why then, do they call it "**url** encoding" whereby the `/` gets encoded to `%2f%`?

Comment: @BGM: I don't understand what you mean by that. Who calls it URL encoding? The spec talks about percent encoding.

Comment: Well, in the javascript function.  The function is called ` encodeURI` and it changes the slash to a token.  Maybe I have something backward?

Comment: @BGM: I don't know JS, but [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) `encodeURI` shouldn't encode a `/`. I did a quick test and it worked, the slash stayed being a slash.

Comment: I'm sorry - you are right `encodeURI` does *not* encode the `/` - I meant `encodeURIComponent`.  I believe your answer is correct, however.  So why does `encodeURIComponent` encode the `/`? Do you know?

Comment: @BGM: Because that is [how `encodeURIComponent` is defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIcomponent): "you should call encodeURIComponent on any user-entered parameters that will be passed as part of a URI". Users shouldn't probably be able to enter reserved characters. So `encodeURIcomponent` encodes *everything* **except**: alphabetic, decimal digits, `- _ . ! ~ * ' ( )`.

Comment: `%2F` does not have hierarchical significance and thus is not treated as `/`. See Example 2 in [W3C's URI recommendations](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html) - taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/42487180/873282