# How to URL Encode a Backslash with R/RCurl

Tags: r, urlencode, rcurl

I'm currently trying to encode a string for insertion into a URL.  My issue is that this seems to fail when my string contains a backslash.  I've tried 4 approaches so far using the URLencode, curlEscape (from RCurl), and curlPercentEncode (from RCurl) functions, but none of them have been successful.

```
> URLencode("hello\hello")
Error: '\h' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""hello\h"
> curlEscape("hello\hello")
Error: '\h' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""hello\h"
> curlPercentEncode("hello\hello")
Error: '\h' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""hello\h"
> curlPercentEncode("hello\hello", amp=TRUE)
Error: '\h' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""hello\h"
```

Comment: Did you try `URLencode("hello\\hello")`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for

```
> URLencode("hello\\hello")
[1] "hello%5chello"
```

The error you're getting is not from any of the functions you tried to call; it didn't get as far as actually calling any of them.  The error is from R's parser.  Backslash is a special character for *string literals themselves,* so you need to write a *double* backslash in your string literal in order to produce a string value containing a backslash.  (There are several other things you can usefully put after the backslash; for instance, `"\""` is how you write a string value consisting of one double-quote character.  Read `?Quotes` for further information.)

Since this is an issue with the syntax of string literals, it shouldn't come up if you're reading the "string for insertion into a URL" from a data source; it should only be an issue if you need to write this string directly in your code.

Comment: On my side, I'm blocked on a particular point. 
I'm trying to put http basic credentials in a link : <a href="https://login:password@host">.  
On my case, password contains \ character and your tip do not work.
Any idea ?

Comment: @DamienC Ask a new question about that please.