# Python error when adding variable with backslash character to URL string

Tags: python, url, cookies, urllib2, backslash

I am trying to scrape some data from a website that assigns a session cookie and generates HTML that contains a crumb code that I need to append to a URL to get to the data. I run into problems (HTTP 401 Unauthorized) when the crumb variable contains a backslash... Since crumb is a variable, I could not figure out how to add r' to the beginning. I have tried adding .encode('string-escape') and .replace('\\','\\\\') to the crumb variable, but I cannot get it to work.

My code, in python 2.7, looks something like this:

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))    
opener.open('http://www.sample.com')

#Some code here that looks for crumb code in HTML

crumb = 'abc\xyz'

#This line fails when crumb contains a backslash
opener.open('http://www.sample.com/data=' + crumb)

cj.clear()
```

Does anyone know how I can avoid the 401 error when trying to open a URL string that contains a backslash?

Also, is it necessary to clear the session cookies each time if I'm looping through multiple crumbs?

**Update: It turns out that the backslashes are being brought in from the \u002F in the HTML. I believe it'll work if I convert these to a forward slash before adding the string to the URL. How can I convert the \u002F in a string to a /?**

Comment: Is `crumb = r'abc\xyz'` sufficient?

Comment: I *think* you need to urlencode that slash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to URL Encode a Backslash with R/RCurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26304172/how-to-url-encode-a-backslash-with-r-rcurl)

Comment: @Nuageux, I cannot because I don't know what the string will be (just used a placeholder for demo).

Comment: @idjaw, I did try to urlencode so it brings in the %5C, but it's still giving me the 401.

Comment: If there is nothing to encode, it won't encode. There is no harm in just calling it to ensure that you always take care of those characters *if* they come up.

Comment: @idjaw, good point-will do. It almost feels like there's a decode that needs to happen somewhere within the opener.open() because it won't get to the page with the %5C...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot use `crumb = r'abc\xyz'`. I believe that `str.encode('string-escape')` function might help. Try:

```
crumb = 'abc\xyz'
crumb.encode('string-escape')
```

Comment: I apologize because my question stated that I tried 'string-encode'. I did, in fact, try 'string-escape', but received the same error. In the interpreter, I can print what is being populated and it shows up as "http://www.sample.com/data=abc"\xyz with everything before the backslash being recognized as a URL, but the rest of it not highlighted as part of the URL. When I encode and it converts the backslash to %5C, the entire string shows up highlighted as a URL, but I still get the 401 error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that "\" is an escape character in python, therefore to make this a raw string not containing any special characters you have to add a "r" before the string. Your code should look like this

```
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))    
opener.open('http://www.sample.com')

#I'm adding a 'r' before the string

crumb = r'abc\xyz'

opener.open('http://www.sample.com/data=' + crumb)

cj.clear()
```

Edit: You may have to encode the "\" for the url request to be formatted right. So "\" would be "%5C".

Comment: I should have added more detail, but that variable is being assigned by searching the HTML from the first website, so I am not able to add the r' to it. Urlencode to %5C gives me the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: @InsuQ Oh okay I see, I'm afraid I cant help you then. Does it work when it's not containing a backslash?

Comment: Yes, when there's no backslash, it works. Other characters, such as dots (.) pass through just fine as well.

Comment: @InsuQ What i'm finding weird is that it's returning a 401 (Unauthorized) I can't really see what's the problem.