# Link to file with utf-8 character in the name

Tags: html, utf

I cannot link any images/files with UTF character in the name.

ex. when I link image to file  i get an error because of "pi%C5%ka+no%C5%BCnaw.png"

I tried to find a solution but his seems to be illuminati secret.

What is the common workaround of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is you must encode any UTF-8 text before you can use them in your HTML code for URLs, don't directly use the UTF-8 text as you did.

For the `Piłka nożna.png` example you posted, it should be percent encoded like this:

```html
<img src="images/ikony/Pi%C5%82ka+no%C5%BCna.png">
```

### Details

Use [encoding](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm) to ensure the browser correctly finds the file. HTML standards are supposed to support [UTF-8 percent encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#utf-8-percent-encode) to properly handle UTF-8 values in URL.

You could use a table to manually encode character by character, but it is easier to search online for a free online encoder.

I just found and used http://www.url-encode-decode.com/ :

Input your original UTF-8 file name:

```html
Piłka nożna.png
```

Output encoded version:

```html
Pi%C5%82ka+no%C5%BCna.png
```

So I put that into your code to get a percent-encoded URL that HTML requires:

```html
<img src="images/ikony/Pi%C5%82ka+no%C5%BCna.png">
```

But do not just input and convert everything into these online converters. If you had input the entire URL `images/ikony...` you would notice forward slashes seem to get percent encoded too.  The reason we choose not to encode `/` as `%2f` is:

> The / is a reserved character. It's not equivalent to %2f. If you need the slash without it's defined meaning, you'd use the encoded form.

Source: [Why Does url-encoding the first slash after the domain break the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631200/why-does-url-encoding-the-first-slash-after-the-domain-break-the-url)

Since we **are** using forward slash for its intended, defined meaning, to mean a directory separator, we leave it as `/` without changing it.