# Why does Django's `urlencode` not encode slash?

Tags: python, django, url, urlencode

I see that Django's `urlencode` filter doesn't encode slash by default:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#urlencode

I know I can make it encode the slash, but why doesn't it do it by default? Isn't it accepted behavior to encode the slash, given that it's a reserved character in URLs?

Comment: Let's see some use cases!

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957115/is-a-slash-equivalent-to-an-encoded-slash-2f-in-the-path-portion-of-a

Answer (score 10):

From the Django source, `urlencode` is basically a wrapper around Django's `urlquote` utility method.  From the comments in the source, `urlquote` is a UTF-8-safe version of `urllib.quote`.

So `urlencode` is using the same defaults as python's `urllib.quote`, and the reason that `urllib.quote` does not escape slashes can be found in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#utility-functions):

> Replace special characters in string using the %xx escape. Letters,
>   digits, and the characters '_.-' are never quoted. By default, this
>   function is intended for quoting the path section of the URL. The
>   optional safe parameter specifies additional characters that should
>   not be quoted — its default value is '/'.

So, the reason is that it's escaping the path, and `'/'` is a perfectly expected and valid character within a path.

Answer (score 2):

To get `urlencode` to also escape `/` in a Django template, use `{{ variable|urlencode:'' }}`.

Explanation: The extra optional parameter tells `urlencode` the set of characters that are "safe", where the default is `'/'`, so passing an empty string is telling `urlencode` that `/` is not safe and should be encoded.