# Do a get request passing a bar as parameter in the url

Tags: parameters, get, request

I am doing a GET request and in my URL has a parameter to search filter of type string.

It turns out that occasionally the user can insert a slash ("/") as a filter, and then an error occurs.

URL:
Http: // localhost: 8080 / api / routes / skip / take / search =

Example:
Http: // localhost: 8080 / api / paths / 0/10 / name = /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider urlencoding your search terms before doing your GET.  (The slash '/' is encoded as %2f.)

Take a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957115/is-a-slash-equivalent-to-an-encoded-slash-2f-in-the-path-portion-of-a) which expands on the above.